# Fresh Activity starts on Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following code that starts activities , The code is for a sub menu that comes out when the user clicks on the Menu button in Android device, The problem with it is that when the button is clicked A new activity starts which looses the previously formed bluetooth connection!

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent serverIntent = null;
        Intent PassIntent;
        Intent PassIntent1;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        /*case R.id.home:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            serverIntent = new Intent(this, engineStarter.class);
            startActivity(serverIntent);
            return true;*/
        /*case R.id.insecure_connect_scan:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);
            return true;*/
        /*case R.id.discoverable:
            // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;*/
        case R.id.setpassword:
            PassIntent = new Intent(this, SetPassword.class);
            startActivity(PassIntent);
            return true;
        case R.id.home:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            serverIntent = new Intent(this, engineStarter.class);
            startActivity(serverIntent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What I actually want is to just load the Activity with its previous state and not create again the acitivity afresh and loose the connection!

Comment: Why not manage the Blue tooth Connection by something like a service ?

Comment: I tried for that but I remember I got stuck at someplace so just didn't went that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1- Change the launch mode of your activity to `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, so it does not create a new instance every time you call `startActivity`

2- Maintain your `Bluetooth` connection in a `service`

There is another possible solution, but might not be elegant one, is to define a custom `application` class where you can maintain the `Bluetooth` connection which in this case will be tight to the `applicationContext`.

Comment: Thanks I will tryout the option one using the singleTask

Comment: "There is another possible solution, but might not be elegant one, is to define a custom application class where you can maintain the Bluetooth connection" - I'm just doing the same at this time but I think i'm not binding it to the same context, Can you throw some more light on this?

Comment: Post your code, because I do not know what you are doing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to keep the same Activity but load new [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) into the activity replacing the current fragment. When using the FragmentManager you can push new fragments onto a stack to navigate forwards and pop them off to navigate backwards. This would allow you to navigate content and keep the Bluetooth connection.